# Multiple entity framework 6 contexts in oracle throw ORA-00955

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 connecting to an oracle database.

I am trying to use multiple contexts with the same schemaName for oracle. But when I create the contexts it appears they share the `__MigrationHistory` table and when the second context attempts to create itself it throws "**ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object**".  To be clear the two contexts I attempted to split by domain design and do not share any entities between the two.

This is the code I'm attempting to run, and it works fine when I run it against SQL Server.  But Oracle throws the ORA-00955 error.

```
try
{
    using (var hContext = new HContextORCL(connectionString, "SchemaName"))
    using (var aContext = new AContextORCL(connectionString, "SchemaName"))
    {
        hContext.Database.Initialize(true);
        aContext.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
}
```

I've tried using `CreateIfNotExists()` instead of the Initialize but receive the same error.  I have tried setting both contexts `Database.SetInitializer<context>(null);` because I don't need the migrations at this point.  But that doesn't seem to work either.

Ideally I would like to keep the `__MigrationHistory` table and have both my contexts initialized in Oracle.  But that's not necessary.  I can sense myself going off the rails trying to figure out all these work-arounds which when I look at them seem overly complicated for something that works in SQL Server.

I am at a loss how to intialize two contexts with the same schema name in an oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for better or worse this is the work around I'm going with.  My issue appears to be the `MigrationHistory` table is shared between the two contexts.

Entity Framework 6 allows you to manipulate the migration table using the `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History` namespace ([Migrations.History Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.history?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)).

So I open the migrations table, copy all the history rows out, delete the migration table, perform my second context initialization and copy the history rows back into the migration database (created during the second context initialization).

```
try
{
    var dbConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    using (var migrationContext = new Migrations.History.HistoryContext(dbConnection, "SchemaName"))
    using (var hContext = new HContextORCL(connectionString, "SchemaName"))
    using (var aContext = new AContextORCL(connectionString, "SchemaName"))
    {
        hContext.Database.Initialize(true);

        List<HistoryRow> currentHistory = migrationContext.History.ToList();
        migrationContext.Database.Delete();

        aContext.Database.Initialize(true);

        currentHistory.ForEach(rowItem => migrationContext.History.Add(rowItem));
        migrationContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```